# Parse comment line

Tags: line, antlr, grammar, comments

Given the following basic grammar I want to understand how I can handle comment lines. Missing is the handling of the `<CR><LF>` which usually terminates the comment line - the only exception is a last comment line before the EOF, e. g.:

```
# comment
abcd := 12 ;
# comment eof without <CR><LF>
```

```
grammar CommentLine1a;

//==========================================================
// Options
//==========================================================



//==========================================================
// Lexer Rules
//==========================================================

Int
  : Digit+
  ;

fragment Digit
  : '0'..'9'
  ;

ID_NoDigitStart
  : ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ) ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Digit )*
  ;

Whitespace
  : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' )+ { $channel = HIDDEN ; }
  ; 


//==========================================================
// Parser Rules
//==========================================================

code
  : ( assignment | comment )+
  ;

assignment
  : id_NoDigitStart ':=' id_DigitStart ';'
  ;

id_NoDigitStart
  : ID_NoDigitStart
  ;  

id_DigitStart
  : ( ID_NoDigitStart | Int )+
  ;

comment
  : '#' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
  ;
```

Comment: What do you mean "handle" comment lines? Are you wondering how to parse them?

Comment: It seems your are trying to handle the comments in your parser grammar, normally whey would get handled in the lexer, similar to your `Whitespace` rule. Are your sure you want to to this in the parser?

Comment: What's not working right now, specifically?  I found this ANTLR mailing list posting from 2006 with basically the same question (and an answer, but it looks similar to what you already have): http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2006-January/015130.html

Comment: Many thanks for your answers!
@john: A very valuable link, a special thank.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unless you have a very compelling reason to put the comment inside the parser (which I'd like to hear), you should put it in the lexer:

```
Comment
  :  '#' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
  ;
```

And since you already account for line breaks in your `Space` rule, there's no problem with input like `# comment eof without <CR><LF>`

Also, if you use literal tokens inside parser rules, ANTLR automatically creates lexer rules of them behind the scenes. So in your case:

```
comment
  :  '#' ~( '\r' | '\n' )*
  ;
```

would match a `'#'` followed by zero or more **tokens** other than `'\r'` and `'\n'` and ***not*** zero or more characters other than `'\r'` and `'\n'`.

For future reference:

### Inside parser rules

- `~` negates tokens
- `.` matches any token

### Inside lexer rules

- `~` negates characters
- `.` matches any character in the range `0x0000` ... `0xFFFF`

Comment: Thanks again Bart for that answer. I wanted to use a parser rule for further processing the comment line. Now I tried to use a parser rule `comment` with just the lexer rule `Comment`, which works, too. But is that the correct way? Are there any more or less common rules when to use a lexer ruler or a parser rule in such situations?

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, comments are almost always single tokens. If you "promote" them to parser rules, you'll also need to remove `'\r'` and `'\n'` from `Space` and create a `LineBreak` token: otherwise you won't be able to "see" when a `comment` (as  a parser rule!) ends.